how to use pivottable's PivotUI with vue 3?
i am trying to use pivotUI of pivottable.js in vue 3 (the only available wrapper is for vue 2).
This is how far i have gotten, i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined". Anybody has any ideas? I think the error comes from jquery-ui
<template>
  <div id="pivotTable" ref="pivotTable"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'pivottable/dist/pivot.css'
import 'jquery-ui'
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'


const tipsData = [
  ['row', 'total_bill', 'tip', 'sex', 'smoker', 'day', 'time', 'size'],
  ['1', 16.99, 1.01, 'Female', 'No', 'Sun', 'Dinner', 2],
  ['2', 10.34, 1.66, 'Male', 'No', 'Sun', 'Dinner', 3],
  ['3', 21.01, 3.5, 'Male', 'No', 'Sun', 'Dinner', 3],
  
]
const pivotTable = ref(null)

onMounted(async () => {
  await import('pivottable')
  $('#pivotTable').pivotUI(tipsData, {
    rows: ['sex', 'smoker'],
    cols: ['day', 'time'],
    vals: ['tip', 'total_bill'],
    aggregatorName: 'Sum over Sum',
    rendererName: 'Heatmap'
  })
})

</script>

<style scoped>
</style>


I am not sure what pivottable does exactly but a few things on it:

it comes with a whopping 80kB of gzipped JS payload if you include jQuery + jQuery UI, which is quite humongous
it is unmaintained for now 6 years, so do not expect things to work if something is being ever changed around the ecosystem
it relies on jQuery, which is not really a good thing as a whole when working with Vue because you will have a very different way of handling the DOM/managing the state
there is absolutely no activity regarding any answers in the issues from people, don't expect to get any kind of help if you have even the simplest question
maintainer still looks active but he only committed 3 times in the past year regarding some very basic markdown pull requests, hence lost total interest into the project

So yes, there are ways to work with it by first installing jQuery properly in it, but...should you?
I highly do not recommend doing so, but if you do make sure that your jQuery import is first working with a basic example of something simple and update us with the result.
Also, double-check that you do not have jQuery written somewhere else in your code.

Finally, consider giving a look to this one), maybe you'll find something more up-to-date and supported that could also solve the issue you're trying to solve.

I am doing this project to showcase vue to the company I work for. This exact pivottable is one of their requirements. I dont won't to be like "well, vue cant do the job, back to react it is". In the end I made it work by adding all the required libraries in the index.html through cdns. I know this is a bad way but at least I meet the requirements now. I may look into what it would take to port the vue wrapper of the pivottable to vue 3 in my free time but I don't have a lot of experience in these stuff
